# AJAX photo slideshow that auto updates from folder

Tags: php, ajax, slideshow, photos

I'm looking for a PHP/AJAX slideshow solution that reads in images from a directory and auto updates while playing when photos are added or deleted. The images should also auto size to the browser dimensions. I have searched for hours and haven't found anything that auto updates. The topic at [Ajax slideshow does not show anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135330/ajax-slideshow-does-not-show-anything/12048147#12048147) is nice but it uses a meta refresh tag which is not dynamic. I know how to adjust this with PHP to dynamically generate the appropriate refresh time on each cycle but this is not ideal with a page refresh. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with something like this ?
[Jquery examples](http://smashinghub.com/23-most-popular-jquery-photo-gallery-and-slider-plugins.htm)

Personally I love this library.

Comment: Thanks but I've seen that site before and none of them seem to handle dynamic updates from a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a timer `window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000);` and when timer reaches 0 fire it again after grabbing new picture. You can have a callback in the same function it is way easier.

```
function yourfunction(){window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000); alert("HELLO");}
```

For the picture either I would get the list on a table in the script or dynamically load a  php page(1st easier if you have all the pictures from a folder, 2nd easier if it loads from database)